# What's the proper way to set up my path in crontab?

Tags: python, cron

I'm new to crontab and having some trouble.

I know that the set up is

```
* * * * *  command to execute
```

and that the * stand for min, hour, day of month, month, day of week respectively

Usually, to run my code in the terminal I do

```
source /Users/mmmm/PycharmProjects/kt/venv/bin/activate
cd tests
python test1.py
```

but I'm not sure how to set that up on crontab. What's the proper way to do so?

Comment: Usually your cron command will point to a bash script or something that handles all the `cd` etc. and then your `python` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bash script. Let's call it `script.sh`

Inside `script.sh` you'll have

`source /Users/mmmm/PycharmProjects/kt/venv/bin/activate
cd tests
python test1.py`

Make sure you make the script executable with `chmod +x script.sh`!

Then you can add that script to crontab with

`* * * * * /path/to/script.sh`

This will activate the the venv, cd into tests and run test1.py while only putting the bash script into cron.

Comment: The first line should use `source`.

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, to be properly portable, the first line should be `#!/bin/bash` if you want to use Bash-only features like the `source` synonym to the POSIX portable command `.` (dot).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a line I used for a django application management command

```
0 */2 * * *  source /Users/jeff/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/activate  && /Users/jeff/ecommapp/manage.py amzn_scrape H >> /Users/jeff/ecommapp/log/scraper_results.log 2>&1
```

Activate the env and then call the command - last logging part is optional.